# Read formatted data from text file in C

Tags: c, regex, io, scanf

What would be the best way to read this data from a `txt` file?

```
12   name1 2     1    65000
13   name2 5   3    30000
17   name3       2       3      30000
20   name4        3    2      58000
```

Notice that the whitespace may change with every line.

I was thinking in doing something like this:

```
while (fscanf(file, "%s\\S{1,}", string) != EOF)
{
    if (!isdigit(*string))
        printf("Name: %s\n", string);

    else if(*string != '0')
        printf("Number: %s \n", string);               
}
```

But, it seems over complicated and inefficient to dynamically store it.

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: "But, it seems over complicated and inefficient to dynamically store it." Are you sure that your example works? I don't ever know `fscanf` accepts a regex as its format string.

Comment: Thanks @user3121023. You are right. If you want I can give you the right answer. You would need to post it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use Regex.

Simply use fscanf as mentioned by user3121023

```
while ( fscanf ( file, "%d %s %d %d %d", &digit[i], &str[i], &number[i], &value[i]) == 4) { i++;}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not very familiar with C. I thought that I had to do something like that.